# Issues using ratchetphp/Pawl websocket client

Tags: slack-api, phpwebsocket

My question is specific to using slack rtm on ratchetphp/Pawl. I have below code which connects fine but dies eventually.

```
            <?php

            require_once "response.php";

            //first make authenticated call to rtm.start    
            use \Curl\Curl;
            $curl = new Curl();

            $rtmStartUrl = "https://slack.com/api/rtm.start?token=xx-xx-xx-xx-xx&pretty=1";
            $curl->get($rtmStartUrl);

            $wsUrl = $curl->response->url;

            $loop = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
            $connector = new Ratchet\Client\Connector($loop);

            $connector($wsUrl)
            ->then(function(Ratchet\Client\WebSocket $conn) {
            $conn->on('message', function(\Ratchet\RFC6455\Messaging\MessageInterface $msg) use ($conn) {
            echo "Received: {$msg}\n";
            // $conn->close();
            });

            $conn->on('close', function($code = null, $reason = null) {
            echo "Connection closed ({$code} - {$reason})\n";
            });

            $conn->send('Hello World!');
            }, function(\Exception $e) use ($loop) {
            echo "Could not connect: {$e->getMessage()}\n";
            $loop->stop();
            });

            $loop->run();
```

Upon running, the output is:

```
            root@ip-172-31-45-75:/var/www/html/slack# php pawl.php 
            Received: {"type":"hello"}
            Received: {"type":"reconnect_url","url":"wss://mpmulti-qpau.slack-msgs.com/websocket/jDkgDysXfZspRj10zqdcrshHK6PhPLItYx2HEkdXy47RPCAJwKgI_NLq0bhS4uMjIT7iRtOoCDUJffcxcr7YdiqMbITUZYqnTmT39Et5a8JeuPLFfCUUzan4MCz34p0jcfAKaQW9G9HpIWrYH4CTqyICZuhgWHnzo8K7dO2zXFc="}
            Received: {}
            Connection closed (1006 - Underlying connection closed)
            root@ip-172-31-45-75:/var/www/html/slack#
```

The websocket is part of slack rtm api (https://api.slack.com/rtm). It seems like when reading on empty websocket, the connection is closed. I think it might be like we listen to slack events (https://api.slack.com/events) sent over websocket for working to avoid disconnect.

Currently, this does not work because of disconnection error.

Comment: Can you give us an idea of how long this code runs before the connection is closed? Also, does this library use WebSocket ping and pong messages? If not, you might need to deal with the Slack API version of those: https://api.slack.com/rtm#ping_and_pong.

Comment: @smarx the code gets disconnected almost immediately (i.e. 1 second or so). Are you saying that I need to add ping messages to keep the socket connection alive? Do you mean to say I need to use different approach than event loop and use a while(1) loop instead. In that while(1) loop, I will keep sending out ping to keep the socket connection alive? Please explain.

Comment: I'd say if you're getting disconnected almost immediately, it's probably not a ping/pong issue.

Comment: Another guess... it could be the "Hello World!" you're sending on the socket? That's not something Slack will process as a valid message... perhaps it hangs up the socket after that message comes across.

Comment: @smarx Oh great! this solved I think. The loop is running 5 minutes for now. Do you think I will hit the ping issue now?

Comment: Only one way to find out. :-) Let it run sometime for an hour or so with no activity to make sure?

Comment: That's really jolly and simple :) How do I mark your comment as answer? Or do you need to post answer again.

Comment: I posted an answer so you can mark it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Hello World!` is not a valid message for this API, so Slack is closing the connection when it receives that message. Try sending something valid (or nothing at all).